# Spring Cloud Stream and GCP pub sub as binder getting stuck

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I tried running the example here
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-binder-sample
I was expecting it to create a topic on my default project. Tomcat service started, but not even the index.html page would load (there should be a message like "Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''"), so it seems it got stuck, and it ocurred after I added:

```
@Autowired
private Source source;
```

Here is the log

```
2019-02-14 12:06:54.305  INFO 3560 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on 2019-02-14 12:06:54.309  INFO 3560 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-02-14 12:06:55.362  INFO 3560 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be 
(http)
2019-02-14 12:06:56.246  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-02-14 12:06:56.247  INFO 3560 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
2019-02-14 12:06:56.257  INFO 3560 --- [           main] 2019-02-14 12:06:56.385  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-02-14 12:06:56.385  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2027 ms
2019-02-14 12:06:56.970  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-02-14 12:06:57.079  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2019-02-14 12:06:57.253  WARN 3560 --- [           main] c.g.a.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.
2019-02-14 12:06:57.383  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.c.GcpContextAutoConfiguration  : The default project ID is xxxxxx-xxxxx
2019-02-14 12:06:58.373  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel nullChannel
2019-02-14 12:06:58.395  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel output
2019-02-14 12:06:58.455  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel errorChannel
2019-02-14 12:06:58.492  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageHandler errorLogger
2019-02-14 12:06:58.525  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2019-02-14 12:06:58.525  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-02-14 12:06:58.525  INFO 3560 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
```

What could be happening??

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination` in your `application.properties`?
The binder will create an anonymous subscription for your topic, if none is configured, but it won't create a topic on its own.

Comment: I did... spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=input
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=input
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=input-sub

Comment: Actually, I was wrong about the topic not being autocreated; the binder does create a topic if it does not exist. Could you check if the topic "input" and subscription "input.input-sub" get created in your GCP project?

Comment: You could also try running the sample with extra spring boot logging, to see if PubSubBinderConfiguration is getting matched: `-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging=DEBUG`

Comment: Actually, stepping back from the pub/sub nature of this, are you behind a proxy? Starting errorLogger is the last thing that happens before the code tries to connect to pubsub.googleapis.com.

Comment: I had implemented a producer using the gcp libraries (no Spring) and it worked...  This is what I'm getting with the extra logging
   PubSubBinderConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.Binder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

Comment: Can you inject `PubSubAdmin` bean and try to call createTopic("testTopic") on it directly? Publishing and subscribing is done over gRPC, but topic/subscription administration is done over HTTP, and so could get independently blocked by a proxy.

`@Autowired PubSubAdmin pubSubAdmin;`

Comment: I checked, and the default transport for admin operations is gRPC, not HTTP. But it's still worth checking whether you can do PubSubAdmin operations manually, since the code is almost definitely getting stuck in PubSubChannelProvisioner either checking that the topic exists or attempting to create one (because you are getting application.errorChannel but not application.output channel in the logs).

Comment: it was a permissions issue. I realize that by using the Pub Sub's api.. But why wasn't that shown in the error log? How can those error be handled?

Comment: I tested the binder sample on a service account with no "pub/sub admin" permission, and got the expected exception when provisioning the binder. 
`Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.`

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions issue. GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment was set incorrectly.